# Render Multiple Modals correctly with map in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to render multiple react-bootsrap modals with map but I am unable to do so. With my current code clicking the 'View Details' button is activating all the modals at the same time instead of opening the relevant modal. Here's a snippet from my code related to the modal:

```
  render() {
    const { accounts } = this.props;
    const displayAccounts = Object.keys(accounts).filter(key => {
      return accounts[key].info.type === 'student'
    }).map(key => {
      return (
        <tr key={key}>
          <th>{accounts[key].info.name}</th>
          <td>{accounts[key].info.email}</td>
          <td><Button bsStyle='danger' onClick={() => this.props.removeAccount(key)}>Remove Account</Button></td>
          <td>
            <ButtonToolbar>
              <Button id={key} bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>View Details</Button>
              <Modal
                id={key}
                show={this.state.show}
                onHide={this.hideModal}
              >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                  <Modal.Title>Student Details</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                  <Table responsive striped hover>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Details</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <td>{accounts[key].userDetails.name}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Education</th>
                        <td>{accounts[key].userDetails.education}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>GPA</th>
                        <td>{accounts[key].userDetails.gpa}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Skills</th>
                        <td>{accounts[key].userDetails.skills}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Overview</th>
                        <td>{accounts[key].userDetails.skills}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </Table>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                  <Button onClick={this.hideModal}>Close</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
              </Modal>
            </ButtonToolbar>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try making the following modifications...

Add the following change to `this.state` in your `constructor` to cache the active Modal index to be assigned later.

```
this.state = {
    ...,
    activeModal: null,
    ...,
}
this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
```

Add/Change the following Event Handlers. The `clickHandler` accepts the click event as well as an index that will be used to set the aforementioned `activeModal` piece of state. When react sees that the state changed it will call the `render` method with the new state.  This is the *Reactive* nature of React.

```
clickHandler(e, index) {
    this.setState({ activeModal: index })
}

hideModal() {
    this.setState({ activeModal: null })
}
```

Do something like this in your `map` function. Notice the `onClick` handler. Use an arrow function to catch the click event and call your `clickHandler`, this is so you can also pass additional arguments (this `index` in this case). Once the `activeModal` piece of state is called the component will be rerendered, upon doing to the `show` prop will evaluate to true for the appropriate `clicked` component.

```
buttonArray.map((button, index) => {
    <Button id={key} bsStyle="primary" onClick={e => this.clickHandler(e, index)}>View Details</Button>
    <Modal
        id={key}
        show={this.state.activeModal === index}
        onHide={this.hideModal}
    />
} )
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This is perfect. Can you please explain the code. I am a beginner at react.

Comment: sure thing, i edited the answer with some more details, hope this helps!

Comment: Great explanation, saved me hours of research.